# How to split this string using Java Regular Expressions

Tags: java, regex

I want to split the string

```
String fields = "name[Employee Name], employeeno[Employee No], dob[Date of Birth], joindate[Date of Joining]";
```

to

```
name
employeeno
dob
joindate
```

I wrote the following java code for this but it is printing only name other matches are not printing.

```
String fields = "name[Employee Name], employeeno[Employee No], dob[Date of Birth], joindate[Date of Joining]";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[.+\\]+?,?\\s*" );

String[] split = pattern.split(fields);
for (String string : split) {
    System.out.println(string);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This part:

```
\\[.+\\]
```

matches the first `[`, the `.+` then gobbles up the entire string (if no line breaks are in the string) and then the `\\]` will match the last `]`.

You need to make the `.+` reluctant by placing a `?` after it:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[.+?\\]+?,?\\s*");
```

And shouldn't `\\]+?` just be `\\]` ?

Comment: I had made the ]+? portion as reluctant but didn't know that has to make the .+ also as reluctant. Thank you

Comment: Bart's right, there shouldn't be a quantifier after the closing `]` at all, much less a reluctant one.

Comment: how should be regex for following string - Ms Abc<abc@gmail.com>;Mr Cde<cde@mail.com>;Miss Xyz<xyz@mail.com>";so i can split the title, name and email id, thanks

Comment: @Apache, if you have a question of your own, I recommend creating a new question.

Answer (score 4):

The error is that you are matching [greedily](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy). You can change it to a non-greedy match:

```
Pattern.compile("\\[.+?\\],?\\s*")
                      ^
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an online regular expression tester at http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?2sa45 that will help you a lot when you try to understand regular expressions and how they are applied to a given input.

Answer (score 0):

WOuld it be better to use [Negated Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to match the square brackets? \[(\w+\s)+\w+[^\]]\]

You could also see a good example [how does using a negated character class work internally (without backtracking)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23662454/how-does-using-a-negated-character-class-work-internally-without-backtracking)