# how to split a string which contains of ( \n : , .)

Tags: java, android

so how can split this combination in android ?

Thanks in advance :)`

i'm trying like that`String lines[] = String.split("\\r?\\n", -1);`
but how can split all data in one time

Comment: `String#split` supports regex, and regex supports an `or` expression

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java regular expression OR operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031805/java-regular-expression-or-operator)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Pattern for regex split

```
String fields = "name[Employee Name], employeeno[Employee No], dob[Date of 
Birth], joindate[Date of Joining]";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[.+\\]+?,?\\s*" );

String[] split = pattern.split(fields);
```

References: [How to split this string using Java Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3881184/5870896)